# Multiple tags about 'blocking', pick one and make all others synonyms?

Tags: support, retag-request

When you go to:

> https://serverfault.com/tags

and type `block`, you will get 3 tags that are all pretty close to each other. Specifically:

- [block](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/block) x 27
- [blocking](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/blocking) x 45
- [blocked](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/blocked) x 25

So, which one should be *the master to rule them all*?

Answer (score 3):

I vote: [block](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/block) to be [theoneringofpower](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/theoneringofpower)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is the word 'block' has multiple meanings.

- Data-block
- To block (verb): to stop someone/something.